# What is reference voltage in a D/A converter

Tags: adc, dac, converter, digital-communications

When I searched on the internet what I got as an answer for the above question is that the reference voltage means the highest voltage tha D/A can output.

But my lecturer at college did a calculation as below.

> An 6 bit A/D has values `110101`.
>   Reference voltage is 0.25V.

Then he multiplies each bit with the two to the power of corresponding to the position and multiply it with the reference voltage. The final value (Vout) is 13.25v. If the definition at the beginning is correct this can't be true since this value is greater than the reference voltage. What does reference voltage mean according to this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference voltage (generally known as Vref) is usually the maximum voltage value that the D/A converter can reach. This value depends on what is connected to the Vref pin. In your case what you mean as the reference voltage is the minimum step of your DAC and it corresponds to the number "000001". What you mean as the reference voltage is the resolution of the converter.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first definition is closer to being correct, but it's not quite right. For an \$N\$-bit D/A converter, the maximum output voltage is produced when the digital input word is equal to \$2^N-1\$, which is the unsigned value with all bits equal to 1. So, the maximum output value is \$V_{max}=((2^N-1)/2^N) * V_{ref}\$. For large values of \$N\$, the maximum output voltage is very close to \$V_{ref}\$.

What your instructor called the "reference voltage" is the voltage equivalent of the LSB: \$V_{LSB}=(1/2^N) * V_{ref}\$.

Comment: Yes, he's using the step voltage (0.25) and calling it the reference voltage (110101 (53) X ).25 = 13.25V